# Regex validation issue

Tags: java, regex

I need  to validate and prevent entering '='(equal sign) for an input string and i use regex to catch it `[=]*`  . but it catches the other strings as well. ex input: 2c450807-4a4c-4f18-bf4f-5a100ced87a0 . above regex catches the this string as well.
please help me.

and also ,can anyone please explain me why this regex doesn't catch the input. I need to catch the special characters mentioned in the regex.

```
            final String REGEX="[.,%*$#@?^<!&>'|/\\\\~\\[\\]{}+=\"-]*";


            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("2c450807-4a4c-4f18-bf4f-5a100ced87a0");

            if (matcher.matches()) {

                System.out.println("found");

            }
            else{

                System.out.println("not found!");
            }
```

this prints "not found!"

Comment: Please provide the full relevant code you have. Maybe you need to use `=` or `=+`? Note `[=]*` may match an empty string, so it will match *any* string.

Comment: You could simple use someString.contains("=") to check if it contains = or not. It will return true if it contains.

Comment: I would suggest to use an English spellchecker, it is very useful to make a better impression from your question.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem you have is that the `*` quantifier allows 0 occurrences of the preceding subpattern. Thus, `[=]*` matches *any* string.

You need to use a mere

```
=
```

And then you [will not match](https://regex101.com/r/oV5xV6/1) `2c450807-4a4c-4f18-bf4f-5a100ced87a0`.

Also please note that `=` is not a special regex character, you do not need to escape it, or place into a character class to avoid escaping.

However, as it has been pointed out in another comment, if you do not have to use a "regex", just check if a string contains `=` with a `str.contains("=")`.

Answer (score 2):

When you use regular expression, you might want to find items depending the number of times they appear:

If you want to match a group containering exactly `n` symbol (in your case: Equal (=) ) you can do something like this:

```
(=){n}
```

ie: if(myVar === myValue) is matched when `n`=3

If you want to match this symbol One or More times:

```
(=)+
```

ie: if((myVar = myValue) or (myVar == myValue) or (myVar === myValue))

If you want to match an item which might appear:

```
(=)*
```

ie: if(myVar < myValue)

The item does not need to be present in your expression to check. The value can be present 0 to `n` times.